# How to use fpm to build packages (deb)

Tags: package

I need to build a few .deb packages to distribute some software locally and I am trying to use fpm: https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm

It is extremely simple to use except that I am missing something really basic.  To wit: How do I set the root dir for the package.   When I run:

```
fpm -s dir -t deb <path to dir I want packaged>
```

the files in the package include the full

What I want is to have the root of the package be the that directory.

```
~/package/
    etc/package.conf
    bin/package
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for a day with this before figuring out that what you need to do is create a packaging directory `<dir>` and then build the package to install into `<dir>/<final install location>`
e.g.

```
mkdir ~/build
cd ~/argus-clients-3.0.8.2/
./configure -prefix=~/build/usr/local
make install
cd ~/build
fpm -s dir -t deb -n argus-clients-3.0.8.2 ./usr
```